# Sonar Jasmine support

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Is there any progress with the Jasmine support in Sonar?
I saw that it was on the road-map but haven't seen any progress with it in the last couple of months.
I tried everything with the jasmine-jstd-adapter and the JsTestDriver with no success.
It managed to create a jsTestDriver.conf-coverage.dat but it is always empty.

Sorry if it is a re-post.

Thanks
Gil

Comment: I agree better integration with established tools is essential if Sonar intends to be in the business of JS code quality).  Though not exactly what you're looking for, [this blog post](http://blog.johnryding.com/post/46757192364/javascript-code-coverage-with-phantomjs-jasmine-and) talks about posting Jasmine code coverage stats to Sonar using JSCover.